# How to remove a specific string from inside the <title> tag of a Wordpress Page

Tags: wp-title

I have some Pages that have a specific string in their Title, e.g. "ASDF".

I want to remove this specific string from ever appearing inside the `<title>` tag on the HTML generated by my theme.

In my functions.php theme file, there's this line:

```
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
```

In my header.php theme file, there's this line:

```
    wp_head();
```

That last line generates a title tag that (say) looks something like this:

```
<title>Blah Blah ASDF &#8211; Blog Name</title>
```

But if "ASDF" appears in the title tag, I want the "ASDF" string to be removed, so the output would be like:

```
<title>Blah Blah &#8211; Blog Name</title>
```

I tried adding the following code to my function.php file:

```
function tweak_custom_title( $title ) {
    return str_replace('ASDF', '', $title); 
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'tweak_custom_title');
```

But that didn't work.

Am I missing a central concept here?

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I was able to get this to work by add a filter to 'document_title_parts' rather than 'wp_title', like so:

```
 add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'tweak_custom_title' );
```